# undefined method `save' making test fail before testing to the end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, railstutorial.org

I am following ruby.railstutorial.org. I have had some troubles, but I solved them. Now, however, I am googling for quite some time, checked the code, I even have an idea why test fails, but have no clue as to how to make it pass.

So, here's the problem. I have a User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name

  validates :name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
   uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end
```

The problem is related to the case insensitive uniqueness check.
The test in **Rspec** is:

```
before { @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com") }
subject { @user }

describe "when email address is already in use" do
    before do
        user_with_same_email = @user.dup
        user_with_same_email = @user.email.upcase
        user_with_same_email.save
    end

    it { should_not be_valid }
end
```

The test error message is as follows:

```
Failures:
1) User when email address is already in use 
    Failure/Error: user_with_same_email.save
    NoMethodError:
    undefined method `save' for "USER@EXAMPLE.COM":String
# ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:53:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

So the model even fails to save. And I have no idea what to do. However, if we comment out the following line from the test:

```
user_with_same_email = @user.email.upcase
```

and remove the **{ case_sensitive: false }** part from the model code, test passes.
What I want the test to do is to actually save the **user_with_same_email** variable and then report that it is **not valid**.
Any help/links/suggestions are very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line does have problem

```
user_with_same_email = @user.email.upcase
```

`user_with_same_email` is an object, you need to set the email attr instead of the object itself.

```
user_with_same_email.email = @user.email.upcase
```

Comment: Thank you! That mistake is so lame, I couldn't even see it. Will pay more attention now.

Answer (score 1):

I was briefly sidetracked by this error in the instruction myself.  In general if one encounters any similar issues I recommend going to the help section of [the tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/help).  If the issue isn't covered there then you could check out the link to the `Official Sample Code` that links to [github](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_2nd_ed).  The code for this issue is correct on that repository.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It's saying user_with_same_email is a string and doesn't have a save method.

Guessing, I'd say you need to create a user object with that email, so you can test that your code finds it and throws the validation.